# installing lxml on the hosting server for python

Tags: python, django, lxml

I had been using mikemaccana-python-docx module for reading from and writing to doc files in python. Now I had to move this feature to hosting server. Can any body suggest a way to install lxml on the hosting server to do the same

Answer (score 2):

On [**Windows**](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)

And on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I want to install it on shared hosting server. Does those guys let me do that ? I think they won't

Comment: If you dnt have access to the server you will have to ask ur Server Admin to do it for you...

Comment: I confirmed from them that they'll not allow them. But as if we are including django modules, can we include these binary files? if so how can we ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml
```

or `sudo pip install lxml`

be sure the libxml-dev installed

Comment: I don't have enough rights to install on shared server. Is there a way to include the executables as if we add django modules?

Comment: If you have ssh access to server you can install it to your home dir. Use --prefix when build and install from source.